# How to manipulate json objects and add key using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

This is the response i'm getting

```
result = [{
    "storeId": "4543",
    "type": "full",
    "overSerializedItems": [3548240, 91511753, 345555],
  },
  {
    "storeId": "5462",
    "type": "half",
    "overSerializedItems": [2548240, 9566666],
  }
]
```

I want to manipulate this json and add key to overSerializedItems.I want to manipulate the response data and need to convert this in below format

```
result = [{
    "storeId": "4543",
    "type": "full",
    "overSerializedItems": [
      {storeId: '3548240'},
      {storeId: '91511753'},
      {storeId: '345555'}
    ],
  },
  {
    "storeId": "5462",
    "type": "half",
    "overSerializedItems": [
      {storeId: '2548240'},
      {storeId: '9566666'}
    ],
  }
]
```

Comment: A single object cannot have same key name `storeId` like `{storeId:3548240,storeId:91511753,storeId:345555}`
You can however have a array of objects like `[{storeId:3548240}, {storeId:91511753},  {storeId:345555}]` to achieve something similar like you require.

Comment: Basically above. If you try to access `obj.overSerializedItems.storeId`, how is the browser supposed to determine which `storeId` you're looking to get?

Comment: _"need to convert this in below format"_ <- why? For one, it's invalid as a JavaScript object. Secondly, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the original format

Comment: I have updated my expected json

Comment: @Uidev123 what did you update? It is still incorrect.

Comment: @Phil but the final structure is still invalid

Comment: The error in the syntax as already pointed out is that you are defining an array with a single object in it and that object has multiple instances of the same member, you can't do this.

Comment: You could have something like ` "overSerializedItems": [{
      storeId: '3548240'},
      {storeId: '91511753'},
      {storeId: '345555'}],` but you cant have same key twice in an object

Comment: @ShanakaRusith I suggested that

Comment: Please see my edited response which i'm expecting

Comment: Turn it on its head, I think what you need is:  "overSerializedItems":{"storeId":["354820","91511753"]}

Comment: Ok, so now it looks like something valid. All you're doing is mapping each `overSerializedItems` to something like `.map(storeId => ({ storeId }))`

Comment: Sorry i posted wrong format corrected it

Comment: @Uidev123 was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two `forEach()` loop for that output:

```js
var result = [{
    "storeId": "4543",
    "type": "full",
    "overSerializedItems": [3548240, 91511753, 345555],
  },
  {
    "storeId": "5462",
    "type": "half",
    "overSerializedItems": [2548240, 9566666],
  }
];

result.forEach(function(obj){
  obj.overSerializedItems.forEach(function(val, index){
    obj.overSerializedItems[index] = {'store':val.toString()};
  });
});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a multiple storeId key in an objet. But you can have multiple object with storeId.

```
overSerializedItems: [{storeId:...}, {storeId:...}]
```

You can transform like that:

```
var result = [
{
   "storeId": "4543",
   "type": "full",
   "overSerializedItems": [3548240,91511753,345555],
},
{
   "storeId": "5462",
   "type": "half",
   "overSerializedItems": [2548240,9566666],
}
];

 var trans = result.map(w => {
  return {
     storeId: w.storeId,
     type: w.type,
     overSerializedItems: w.overSerializedItems.map(x => { return {storeId: x.toString()} })
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to convert `x` to a string

Comment: @Phil yeah. That was what I added in my answer :)

Comment: Why are you making thing complex with `map()` couple of `forEach()` would work as OP needs to change the same `result` array:

Comment: For me it's more simple to read lambda expression with map instead of nested foreach

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal perhaps OP doesn't want to mutate the original data. Treating data as immutable, especially in transform operations is often a very good idea

Comment: @Phil, better answer than mine :D. I agree with you